Average number of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points over twists of a variety
Let $p \gg 1$ be a sufficiently large prime. I recently stumbled across a fascinating fact about the number of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points on  elliptic curves over finite fields. Specifically, we have:
Fact 1. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$, and denote its quadratic twist by $E'$. Then the average number of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points on $E$ and $E'$ is equal to $p+1$; i.e., we have
$$\frac{1}{2}\big(\#E(\mathbb{F}_p) + \#E'(\mathbb{F}_p)\big) = p+1.$$
In particular, this average is independent of the choice of $E$.
Proof of Fact 1. Take a model of the form $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$ for $E$, and denote by $(\frac{\cdot}{\cdot})_2$ the quadratic residue symbol. Then we have
$$\#E(\mathbb{F}_p) + \#E'(\mathbb{F}_p) = 1 + \sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p} \left[1 + \left(\frac{x^3 + Ax + B}{p}\right)_2\right] + 1 + \sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p} \left[1 - \left(\frac{x^3 + Ax + B}{p}\right)_2\right] = 2p + 2. \square$$
I believe the same sort of thing holds for families of cubic twists of elliptic curves:
Fact 1'. Let $E$ be a Mordell curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$, i.e., a curve with equation $y^2 = x^3 + k$, where $k \in \mathbb{F}_p^\times$. Then the average number of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points on cubic twists of $E$ of the form $E^D \colon y^2 = x^3 + kD^2$ is equal to $p+1$; i.e., we have
$$\frac{1}{\#\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}/\mathbb{F}_p^{\times^3}}\sum_{D \in \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}/\mathbb{F}_p^{\times 3}} \#E^D(\mathbb{F}_p) = p+1.$$
In particular, this average is independent of the choice of $k \in \mathbb{F}_p^\times$.
What I find so interesting about Facts 1 and 1' is that they admits analogues in many other settings of arithmetic and geometric interest. For example, let $V \simeq \mathbb{A}^4$ be the space of binary cubic forms (i.e., homogeneous degree-$3$ polynomials in two variables). Given $f,g \in V(\mathbb{F}_p)$, we say that $f$ and $g$ are twists of each other if $f,g$ are $\operatorname{GL}_2(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$-equivalent. It is known that the action of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$ is transitive on the set of forms in $V(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$ having a given nonzero discriminant. Thus, if $f,g \in V(\mathbb{F}_p)$ have the same nonzero discriminant, then $f$ and $g$ are twists of each other.
Fact 2. Let $\Delta \in \mathbb{F}_p^\times$, and let $V_\Delta$ denote the fiber of the discriminant map $\operatorname{disc}\colon V \to \mathbb{A}^1$ above $\Delta$. Then the average number of zeros of binary cubic forms in $V_\Delta(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is equal to $1$; i.e., we have
$$\frac{1}{\#V_\Delta(\mathbb{F}_p)}\sum_{f \in V_\Delta(\mathbb{F}_p)} \#\{(x : y) \in \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_p) : f(x,y) = 0\} = 1.$$
In particular, this average is independent of the choice of $\Delta \in \mathbb{F}_p^\times$.
Proof of Fact 2. If $\Delta$ is a quadratic residue, then a binary cubic form of discriminant $\Delta$ is either totally split over $\mathbb{F}_p$ or irreducible. These factorization types occur with frequencies in a ratio of $1 : 2$. On the other hand, if $\Delta$ is a quadratic nonresidue, then a binary cubic form of discriminant $\Delta$ has one quadratic factor. $\square$
Here is another $0$-dimensional example.
Fact 3. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$. The average number of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points on twists of the $2$-torsion subscheme $E[2]$ is equal to $1$; i.e., we have
$$\frac{1}{\#H^1\big(\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p/\mathbb{F}_p),E[2]\big)}\sum_{\sigma \in H^1\big(\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p/\mathbb{F}_p),E[2]\big)} \#\big(E[2]^\sigma(\mathbb{F}_p)\big) = 1.$$
Proof of Fact 3. The twist by $\sigma$ of $E[2]$ is trivial if and only if $E[2]^\sigma(\mathbb{F}_p) \neq \varnothing$. It is easy to see that $\#H^1\big(\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p/\mathbb{F}_p),E[2]\big) = \#E[2](\mathbb{F}_p)$. $\square$
My question: Is there some general underlying principle that explains all of these examples? Or is there a general framework in which all of these examples live? E.g., let $X \to S$ be a morphism of varieties over $\mathbb{F}_p$, where for every $s \in S(\mathbb{F}_p)$, the fiber $X_s(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is a "twist family." Then under some reasonable conditions, perhaps it is the case that the average over $Y \in X_s(\mathbb{F}_p)$ of $\#Y(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is independent of the choice of $s$?

This may be less deep than you think. For example Fact 1 can be simply explained by noting that every point on the projective line can be lifted either to two points on $E$ or to two points on its twist $E'$, except for the four branch points which each give one point on both $E$ and $E'$. And this is a general fact about twists: we can decompose the rational points on a quotient $X/G$ in terms of the rational points on twists $X_{\sigma}$ coming from cocycles with values in $G$. (Once again you have to pay some extra attention to branch points, but this is the general principle.)

@R.P. Thanks for this answer! I see how your explanation justifies the facts I mentioned. I have some higher-dimensional examples in mind that I'm not sure how to fit into the $X/G$ framework. E.g., based on some experiments, I think the average number of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points on quartic del Pezzo surfaces over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is $p^2 + p+ 1 = #\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ --- perhaps this has to do with the rationality of such surfaces?

My guess would be that it's something else, because the fact that they're rational doesn't imply that they have the same number of points as the projective plane. For example by blowing up P^2 in a point you get $p^2+2p+1$ for the count, but it's still a rational surface. My suggestion would be to look at the total space formed by all del Pezzo surfaces under consideration, and count the points on that. One can hope that it has a simple to understand geometry...
